# issue in Call JSON url multiple time in single Asynsctask android

Tags: android, json

```
  public class GetUserDetail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(PropertyDetailActivitys.this, "Wait", "User Detail");

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response

            System.out.println("Size mArrayListReviewDetails "+mArrayListReviewDetails.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListReviewDetails.size(); i++) {

                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("https://graph.facebook.com/"+mArrayListReviewDetails.get(i).getFromid(), ServiceHandler.GET);
                System.out.println("JSON OP USer"+"{"+"\"User\""+":"+jsonStr.toString()+"}");
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    System.out.println("Name "+jsonObj.getString("name"));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (mProgressDialog!=null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }
```

**ServiceHandler.Java**

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
  }
```

Hello friends this is my code in this i have **mArrayListReviewDetails Arraylist** which include size and as per that size i want to get user name which i call next web service as below ,,right now this arraylist size is **11** but when i call this service it will get only **2** data and progress dialog progress continueouly so how can i solve it any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just make change in doINBackground fun. Take 
**ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();** line inside for loop

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        // Making a request to url and getting response

        System.out.println("Size mArrayListReviewDetails "+mArrayListReviewDetails.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListReviewDetails.size(); i++) {
             ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("https://graph.facebook.com/"+mArrayListReviewDetails.get(i).getFromid(), ServiceHandler.GET);
            System.out.println("JSON OP USer"+"{"+"\"User\""+":"+jsonStr.toString()+"}");
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                System.out.println("Name "+jsonObj.getString("name"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass your parameters to the async task:

```
public class GetUserDetail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... usernames) {
        for (int i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("https://graph.facebook.com/" + usernames[i], ServiceHandler.GET);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, instead of String, feel free to pass your own type. To call the async task:

```
new GetUserDetail().execute( "test1", "test2" );
```

Other option is to have each async task perform exactly one single webservice call and create many of them. Advantage: on Android 3.0+, the task executions will be done in parralel.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using that...you can use "Volley" library...it's simple and having build-in functionality like;

> 1. Request queuing and prioritization
> 2. Effective request cache and memory management
> 3. Extensibility and customization of the library to our needs
> 4. Cancelling the requests

[volley reference](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

[volley tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)